# Strange call stack, could it be problem in asio's usage of openssl?

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I have this strange call stack and I am stumped to understand why.

It seems to me that asio calls open ssl's read and then gets a negative return value (-37) .

Asio seems to then try to use it inside the memcpy function.

The function that causes this call stack is used hunderds of thousands of times without this error.

It happens only rarely, about once a week.

```
ulRead = (boost::asio::read(spCon->socket(), boost::asio::buffer(_requestHeader, _requestHeader.size()), boost::asio::transfer_at_least(_requestHeader.size()), error_));
```

Note that request header's size is exactly 3 bytes always.

Could anyone shed some light on possible reasons?

Note: I'm using boost asio 1.36

Here is the crashing call stack crash happens in memcpy because of the huge "count":

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: Is it BIO_read returning -37?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but 4294967259 as a signed number would be -37

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: It appears something *bad* happens in _EVP_CIPHER_set_asn1_iv. Perhaps data somewhere is getting trashed slowly (you noted it happens gradually over time). Eventually leading to the untimely death of memcpy.

Comment: Sometimes it will happen the same day, sometimes within a couple weeks, sometimes a week.  So I think it is not something that is gradual.  But it is rare that it happens.    OK so you think it is some type of memory corruption in an unrelated part of code?

Comment: Note all connections use the same ssl context, so this is why I asked if it was ok in the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at evp_lib.c shows that it tries to pull a length from the cipher context, and in your case gets a Very Bad Value(tm). It then uses this value to copy a string (which does the memcpy). My guess is something is trashing your cipher, be it a thread safety problem, or a reading more bytes into a buffer than allowed.

[Relevant source](http://google.com/codesearch?hl=en&q=show:_xVlO8chB2g:XjlEV0kP4tQ:47QgajN6ofA&sa=N&ct=rd&cs_p=http%3A//www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.7j.tar.gz&cs_f=openssl-0.9.7j/crypto/evp/evp_lib.c):

```
int EVP_CIPHER_set_asn1_iv(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *c, ASN1_TYPE *type)
{
int i=0,j;

if (type != NULL)
    {
    j=EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(c);
    OPENSSL_assert(j <= sizeof c->iv);
    i=ASN1_TYPE_set_octetstring(type,c->oiv,j);
    }
return(i);
}
```

Comment: I think I'll try to refactor the usage of the SSL context and see if it helps. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: not a problem, a quick check would be to put something before your context on the stack and see if it gets trashed instead.